# Mysql Module Does Not Load in phpinfo();

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Version:

Windows 7 Home Premium

Php 5.2.10

Apache 2.2.22

Mysql 5.6.25.0

## Here's my configuration:

```
My Php.ini file is under C:/Windows
My Php is installed in this directory: D:\Tools\Webcoding\php
```

And in my **Php.ini** file, I have:

```
Extension_dir="D:\Tools\WebCoding\php\ext"
Extension=Php_mysql.dll
Extension=Php_mysqli.dll
```

---

My httpd.conf file is in this directory: `D:\Tools\WebCoding\apache\conf`.And in my **httpd.conf** file I have:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/Windows"
LoadModule Php5_module "D:/Tools/WebCoding/php/Php5apache2_2.dll
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

`localhost:8080/test.php` contains the following in case any of you need to know.

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:
C:\Windows\php.ini
```

However, localhost:8080/test.php Does Not Load Mysql Module. I tried anything I can find, but none of the information helped fix the problem.

1. I tried forward and backward slashes, and adding extra slash in the end of ext.
2. I tried putting php_mysql.dll under "Windows/system32".
3. I tried adding "C:\Windows;" into environment variable Path

p.s. I'm sure my mysql server is up and running well. mysql client runs with no issue either. So the problem I assume is still configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Problems solved!!!I found it! It works now.
libmysql.dll was not located in my system path.

For anyone who would run into the same problem:

Make sure your php_mysql.dll and libmysql.dll are located in your system path, which you should check for your environment variable path.